# Why doesn't msmq send() work?

Tags: c#, .net, message-queue, sendmessage

I have a private msmq setup on my machine.  I'm able to successfully connect with the queue using a .NET console app.

However, when I execute Send("my message"), I never see any messages show up in the queue.  Does anyone know why that might be happening?  I don't get any exceptions.

```
MessageQueue queue = new MessageQueue(queuePath);
queue.Send("test message");
```

Comment: My crystall ball is in maintenance this week. Care to show us your code?

Comment: Is that all of it? No transactions, no extras?

Comment: That's it.  I'm only testing at this point.

Comment: So I checked it and it seems like there are many cases where it's the message queue manager that's messed up, and the MessageQueue class will fail silently (no. 1 deadly sin devs can do, IMO).

Comment: I couldn't find something in SO but I found this discussion: http://microsoft.public.msmq.programming.narkive.com/g7EAJbFL/message-is-lost-after-calling-c-messagequeue-send . Check this out: `"The destination Queue manager will then try to deliver the message to the queue. If the queue doesn't exist or if the queue's security doesn't allow the sender to write to the queue or if one of a number of other problems exist the message can't be delivered but MSMQ can't throw an exception."`

Comment: I'm not sure how to troubleshoot this than.  CanRead and CanWrite are true.  Authenticate is false.  Is there some way to get the exception out of MessageQueue?

Comment: I don't know. I've also never had this problem before. I would try MSDN besides SO, just to have more chances to get a proper answer.

Comment: It's a transactional queue.  The send code here solve the problem: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d787y5ww.aspx.